# What's the purpose of the jumper on my XFX GeForce GTS 250 video card?

Tags: graphics-card, jumper

My graphics card is XFX GeForce GTS 250 1 GB. I've noticed that there is a **jumper** on the top of the board - top means the opposite side of the PCIe connector. The jumper is **not connected**. I couldn't find anything about the jumper in specs. May be it is not to be used for customers but I'm curious, what's the jumper doing on the board?

Comment: It might not necessarily be a jumper - it might be a 2 pin connector of some sort. Is there any silkscreened letters near it?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: not sure what is silkscreened letter, but there is no letter nearby.

Comment: slikscreening is the process they use to put those white letters on a green, black or red circuit boards - quite often circuits have almost every part labelled to some extent, which can be useful in identification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an SPDIF connector, it's so that you can stream audio through your HDMI connector.

Comment: there is no HDMI connector on the board. what's the purpose of this SPDIF connector? where have you find this information?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/PDIF

You might not have an HDMI port on your card in which case you have a S/PDIF connector on your card, you use it if you're connecting your PC to a digital sound system or more commonly to a monitor with speakers. You could use an HDTV instead of a regular monitor, and connect it all via your graphics card. I got my information from a number of different posts on http://www.tomshardware.com and product documentation on what the included cables are used for. Some users claim that they are able to stream audio over the DVI port when using a DVI/HDMI converter.